# How to get an array throughout a controller?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I'm trying to create a simple shopping cart and have an `addToCart` function where it's meant to do what is says.

```
   /** 
     * Creates the option to 'add product to cart'.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/addToCart", name="product_addToCart")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function addToCartAction(Request $request, $id) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $product = $em->getRepository('ShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);

        $cartArray = $this->setEmptyCartArray();

        if ($this->checkUserLogin()) {

            $this->addFlash('notice', 'Login to create a cart');

        } else {

            // $cartArray[] = [$product->getId(), $product->getName(), $product->getPrice()];
            $cartArray[$product->getId()] = [$product->getName(), $product->getPrice()];      
                                            //think of a way to do this without using product
            // $cartArray = $this->setCartArray($product);  //SAME RESULT----------------------------
            // $this->setCartArray($cartArray);
            // var_dump($cartArray); die;
            // $cartArray = $this->putInGetCartArray();     //SAME RESULT--------------------------------
            $this->putInGetCartArray($cartArray);
            // var_dump($cartArray); die;
            $this->addFlash('notice', 'The product: '.$product->getName().' has been added to the cart!');

        }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('product');

    }
```

I need that array to go to my `showCart` function where I show the user what they placed in their cart.

```
/**
 * Shows Empty Cart
 *
 * @Route("/showCart", name="product_showCart")
 * @METHOD("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showCartAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // $id = ;

    $product = $em->getRepository('ShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);

    $user = $this->getUser();

    $totalCostOfAllProducts = 0;

    // $cartArray = $this->setEmptyCartArray();
    // $cartArray = 
    // $cartArray[] = [];
    $this->setCartArray($product);
    $this->putInGetCartArray($cartArray); 

    // $totalCostOfAllProducts = $this->getTotalCost($em, $cartArray, $totalCostOfAllProducts);

    if (empty($price) && empty($quantity) && empty($totalCostOfAllProducts) && empty($cartArray)) {
        $price = 0; $quantity = 0; $totalCostOfAllProducts = 0; $cartArray = [];
    }

    return array(
        'user'  => $user,
        // 'qaunt' => $quant,
        'cartArray' => $cartArray,
        'totalCostOfAllProducts'    => $totalCostOfAllProducts,
    );
}
```

(btw I know this produces an error as it stands now...$id undefined...)

I've created a couple different helper methods within the controller but I can't seem to get everything working together right. I get an `$id` in `addToCart` but in `showCart` I do not and that complicates things because I can't simply set the array again as I need the `$id`, `$name`, and `$price` from my Entity.

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private function setEmptyCartArray() {
        $cartArray = array();
        return $cartArray;
    }
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // private function setCartArray($em, $id) {

    //     // $cartArray = array();
    //     // var_dump($cartArray); die;
    //     // foreach ($cartArray as $key => $value) {
    //         $product = $em->getRepository('ShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);
    //         // $id = $productID->getId();
    //         // var_dump($id); die;
    //         $cartArray[$product->getId()] = [$product->getName(), $product->getPrice()];
    //         // $cartArray[] = [$productID->getName(), $productID->getPrice()];
    //     // }

    //     return $this;

    // }
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private function setCartArray($product) {


        // $this->cartArray = $cartArray;
            $cartArray[$product->getId()] = [$product->getName(), $product->getPrice()];
            // $cartArray[] = [$productID->getName(), $productID->getPrice()];
        // }

        // return $this;
        return $cartArray;

    }
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private function putInGetCartArray($cartArray) {

        // $cartArray = $this->setCartArray ($product);
        // $cartArray = $this->setCartArray($cartArray);
        $userCartArray = $cartArray;

        // return $this->cartArray;
        return $userCartArray;

    }
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

If you have any questions or need more clarity, I'd be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to have a functioning shopping cart without changing a lot of your code since it doesn't look like you're actually storing any data anywhere, I mean that you should probably keep track of your cart's content using sessions or database or whatever, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Anyways, let's say you just want to show your cart's content once, and let it get reset on the next request, you could either pass your array as an argument to the `showCartAction` function, something like this :

```
public function addToCartAction(Request $request, $id) {
    // ...
    else {

        $cartArray[$product->getId()] = [$product->getName(), $product->getPrice()];      
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'The product: '.$product->getName().' has been added to the cart!');
        $this->showCartAction($request, $cartArray);
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
public function showCartAction(Request $request, $cart = array()) {
    // ...
}
```

Or you could also store the array as one of your controller's property, like this :

```
class CartController extends Controller {

    private $cartArray = array();

    public function addToCartAction(Request $request, $id) {
        // ...
        else {
            // Set the property here
            $this->cartArray[$product->getId()] = [$product->getName(), $product->getPrice()];      
        }
        // ...
    }

    // ...
    public function showCartAction(Request $request) {
        return array(
            'user'  => $user,
            'cartArray' => $this->cartArray, // Access the array here
            'totalCostOfAllProducts' => $totalCostOfAllProducts,
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot. I do want to store these values in a database though as well. Could you give me an idea on how to do this too? Also I was using sessions before but figured it as problematic and decided to change it to this. And could you explain what you mean by the Set the property here comment in the second example?

Comment: The comment `// Set the property here` refers to the next line in the code where you'll want to properly set the property's content so there actually is something to access from your `showCartAction` function.
If you want to store your cart in the database, a way of doing this would be to create a `Cart` entity with a relation to the user it belongs to, and another one for the items the cart contains.

Comment: If you're new to Symfony, I'd recommend you read this excellent doc from Symfony's website : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html It should help you get a grip on how Doctrine entities work and how to make relations between them.